# Speed up MYSQL query that has order by

Tags: mysql

I got 300,000 rows in 'tblmessages', and I'm trying to run this query.
If U don't use "order by msgId desc" It's run very fast, but when I add the order It's very very slow.

What am I missing...?

[my index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVsRg.png)
[image]

```
    SELECT msgId  
    FROM tblmessages 
    left join  wp_users as a on a.ID  = (CASE WHEN (msgFromUserId=1) then tblmessages.msgToUserId else  tblmessages.msgFromUserId END)
    left join tblforum_users u1 on u1.user_ID  =(CASE WHEN (msgFromUserId=1) then tblmessages.msgToUserId else  tblmessages.msgFromUserId END)
    where (msgFromUserId=1 or msgToUserId=1) 
    order by msgId desc limit 0,20
```

after Explain:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type        | possible_keys                         | key                                   | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | tblmessages | NULL       | index_merge | IXtbl_messages_from,IX_tblmessages_to | IX_tblmessages_from,IX_tblmessages_to | 5,5     | NULL | 726454 | 100.00   | Using union(IX_tblmessages_from,IX_tblmessages_to); |
                                                                                                                                                                                   Using where; Using filesort                         |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | a           | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                               | PRIMARY                               | 8       | func | 1      | 100.00   | Using where; Using index                            |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | u1          | NULL       | eq_ref      | PRIMARY                               | PRIMARY                               | 4       | func | 1      | 100.00   | Using where; Using index                            |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

and more information about `tblmessages`:

```
Data    12.1    GiB
Index   190.8   MiB
Total   12.3    GiB
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i add the infornation u ask. thenks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons for this:

> If U don't use "order by msgId desc" It's run very fast, but when I
>   add the order It's very very slow.

1st is that your query has a "LIMIT 20" rows at the end of it. Ordering your results for this query (via "order by") will require *all* rows which satisfy the where clause to be pulled/generated,sorted,etc. in order to get the correct 20 rows.

2nd is sort-of subjective, but I'll say your table's don't have the necessary indexing to support optimization of that query. Or, another way of looking at it, could be a query like that is generally gonna run slowly because of the multiple joins on IF-THEN clauses. My advice on fixing this is to either simplify the query into multiple queries or update your question with "SHOW CREATE TABLE" statements for the relevant tables along with one of those INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries that summarizes indices, partitions, etc. From there we could potentially update design (e.g. adding multi-column indices/indexes/however its spelled...)